# flexigrid column drag indicator is not displaying properly in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, flexigrid

In Mozilla and IE g.cdpad return as 11 but in Chrome this return as 12. so my Drag indicator is shows 1px away in incremental way.

flexigrid.js line 1034

```
        g.cdpad = 0;
        g.cdpad += (isNaN(parseInt($('div', cdcol).css('borderLeftWidth'))) ? 0 : parseInt($('div', cdcol).css('borderLeftWidth')));
        g.cdpad += (isNaN(parseInt($('div', cdcol).css('borderRightWidth'))) ? 0 : parseInt($('div', cdcol).css('borderRightWidth')));
        g.cdpad += (isNaN(parseInt($('div', cdcol).css('paddingLeft'))) ? 0 : parseInt($('div', cdcol).css('paddingLeft')));
        g.cdpad += (isNaN(parseInt($('div', cdcol).css('paddingRight'))) ? 0 : parseInt($('div', cdcol).css('paddingRight')));
        g.cdpad += (isNaN(parseInt($(cdcol).css('borderLeftWidth'))) ? 0 : parseInt($(cdcol).css('borderLeftWidth')));
        g.cdpad += (isNaN(parseInt($(cdcol).css('borderRightWidth'))) ? 0 : parseInt($(cdcol).css('borderRightWidth')));
        g.cdpad += (isNaN(parseInt($(cdcol).css('paddingLeft'))) ? 0 : parseInt($(cdcol).css('paddingLeft')));
        g.cdpad += (isNaN(parseInt($(cdcol).css('paddingRight'))) ? 0 : parseInt($(cdcol).css('paddingRight')));
```

Can Anyone explain why chrome returning wrong value Or which of the property is not parsed properly by chrome.